# How to execute script using webview2 to expand an html element using c#

Tags: c#, webview2

I'm not quite sure how to ask this question. So I'm attaching two images

[image]

[image]

How can I expand the Product Details tab so that the html rendered in the webview2 control looks like the second picture using code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject script into a page using `CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync` that will find that element and perform a click on it. However, this will be a fragile solution since if the layout of the page or names of elements on the page change your script may no longer work.

I would recommend opening the desired page in the Edge browser, opening DevTools, Console, and trying out different script to click on the correct element. For example `document.getElementById("product-section-overview").children[0].children[0].click()` might work but depends on the ID of that element not changing, and the structure and order of its children.

Once you have the script you want you can inject it into the document via

```cs
await myWebView2.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById("product-section-overview").children[0].children[0].click()");
```

Comment: One more question tho. Why WebView2.coreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("my script"); and not just WebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("my script");

Comment: There are different WebView2 classes for each supported UI framework (right now there's one for WinForms, WPF, WinUI2, and WinUI3 produced by Microsoft) and each one is a little different with the goal of integrating WebView2 into the corresponding UI framework and providing access to the most common APIs. But each one has a CoreWebView2 property that is the same across all WebView2 classes and that provides consistent and complete WebView2 API access including ExecuteScriptAsync.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a library for use with `WebView2` that provides a `DOM API` and automation functionality then you can try [WebView2.DevTools.Dom](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebView2.DevTools.Dom/). It's free for anyone to use.

```cs
// Add using WebView2.DevTools.Dom; to access the CreateDevToolsContextAsync extension method

// Only a single WebView2DevToolsContext should exist at any given time, when you are finished them make sure you dispose via DisposeAsync. The WebView2DevToolsContext can be reused if required
await using var devToolsContext = await webView.CoreWebView2.CreateDevToolsContextAsync();

// Get element by Id
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
var element = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlElement>("#myElementId");

// Click The element
// This will simulate a mouse move then click
await element.ClickAsync();
```

More details and examples in the [Readme](https://github.com/ChromiumDotNet/WebView2.DevTools.Dom#dom-access)